# The activities in android studio don't switch after pressing the button

Tags: java, android

I've already tried searching the Google on how to switch activities in android studio, even in the official documentation with tutorial. I did it exactly like it was said but I am still unable to get redirected to another activity after clicking a button.

I've entered an onClick name of the method to the button

it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCPTW.png (can't post images yet)

and this is my MainActivity.class file with said method

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void handleButtonAddNew(View view) {
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddItemActivity.class));
    }
}
```

After pressing the button in a phone, the button does nothing.

This is my AddItemActivity.class

```java
public class AddItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);
    }


    public void handleButtonRemember(View view) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

How come the button doesn't work, what did I do wrong?

### EDITS

**EDIT: Successfully ran emulator and the buttons did in fact work, the problem lies within my phone, the buttons there don't want to work. Where could be the issue now?**

**EDIT: XML Layout of MainActivity.class**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAddNew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="188dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="188dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="264dp"
        android:text="@string/buttonAdd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="715dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT: The problem was with scroll view blocking the clickable button so on my phone the button didn't register any clicks, after removing the scrollview the button works normally.**

Comment: Put log inside handleButtonAddNew, see if your method is even getting called

Comment: Try removing the View from your method parameters since it's not being used. Also, you could try binding your views and programmatically setting an onClickListener to your button that starts the activity instead. At least this way it would make the debugging more obvious.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo if the onClick is registered in XML rather than programmatically which seems to be the case, it is required to have the view as a parameter.

Comment: Is your new activity registered in the app Manifest file?

Comment: You might want to include your activity_main.xml file.

Comment: @brandonx So, the problem apparently lies within my phone. After successfully running the emulator on my laptop (had trouble with that as my laptop is not really good), I tried it withint the emulator and everything works. The problem is that after createing an apk and installing it in my phone, the button doesn't do anything. Where could be the problem?

Comment: @Antrophy Try removing the onClick attribute from your XML and registering the clickListener via the method in my answer and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that this button doesn't get any listeners attached.

### The programatic approach

From the [Official Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button)

I'd suggest you use this in your `onCreate` callback:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_btn_id);
button.setOnClickListener((view) -> { theMethodYouWantToCallHere(view); });
```

### XML approach

**Please double check the following using this approach**

1. Your activity is registered in the `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. You're including the `android` namespace to the XML file in the parent container of the layout file. IE: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
3. Make sure you're setting the content view for the activity with `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file);`
4. Once 2 is satisfied make sure you're using the `android` namespace. IE: `android:onClick="yourMethod"`
5. As you're currently doing: Make sure the `onClick` callbacked method has the `View view` parameter; **no more, no less**
6. Make sure the `onClick` function is `public` in the activity.
7. And that no other clickable views are covering the view you're registering the `onClick` listener for :)
   Including the namespace: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

**XML file**

```
<FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button android:text="Click me!"  android:onClick="clicked" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**The activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void clicked(View view){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hey! Im clicked!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried the programmatic approach, the emulator works as it should, the activity switches, however, my phone doesn't register the clicks. It doesn't even show the animation that the button is clicked once I click the button with my finger.

Comment: A screenshot of the layout inside the emulator would also serve some help

Comment: [Inside design creation](https://i.imgur.com/pW61am6.png)  

[Inside Emulator](https://i.imgur.com/6Oe57MW.png)

Comment: I think the button may be too small on the real device and/or the `ScrollView` is on top of the `Button` and catching the click events.

Try debugging it with `<ScrollView android:visibility="gone" ...` and see if it works

Comment: Yes, scrollView was blocking the vision of the button, it works now, thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help! :D